# Frequency spectrum and unit impulse response

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, control-theory, signal-processing

In the context of signal processing, consider the following system:
$$
 x\left( t \right) \to System\, A \to z\left( t \right) \to System \, B
 \to y\left( t \right)  
.$$

Let the global system be the "union" of system A and system B. The input and
output of System A are represented by the equations:

$$
 \frac{d^2 \, z(t)}{d \, t^2} + 6 \frac{d\, z(t)}{d\, t} + 8 z\left( t
 \right) = \frac{d\, x(t)}{d\, t} + 2x\left( t \right) 
$$

and the unit impulse response of System B is defined as follows:
$$
 h_B  \left( t \right) = t e^{-3t} u\left( t \right) 
.$$

Q1: What is the unit impulse response of the global system?
Q2: For a periodic input of the form
$$
 x\left( t \right) =e^{-t} \quad ; \quad -1<t<0
.$$ 
with a period of $T=1$, what will the output signal  $y\left( t \right) $ be?
Q3: What is the frequency spectrum of that last signal?

---

Note: In this problem $u(t)$ denotes the [unit step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Integral_representations). And I found [these](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Transient/TransInputs/TransImpulseTime.html) [three](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528541/is-impulse-response-always-differentiation-of-unit-step-response-of-a-system) [articles](http://web.mit.edu/6.02/www/s2012/handouts/12.pdf) that I think are related.

**Edit:** With the help of @KwinvanderVeen , I tried to solve it by finding the transfer function for both systems.
$$ H_A(s)= \frac{Z\left( s \right) }{X\left( s \right) } =
\frac{\mathcal{L}\{z\} \left( s \right) }{\mathcal{L}\{ x\}\left( s \right) }=
\frac{\int^{\infty}_{0} z\left( t \right) e^{-st} dt}{\int^{\infty}_{0} x\left( t \right) e^{-st} dt }$$

And for the system B:
$$ H_B(s)= \frac{Y\left( s \right) }{Z\left( s \right) } =
\frac{\mathcal{L}\{y\} \left( s \right) }{\mathcal{L}\{ z\}\left( s \right) }=
\frac{\int^{\infty}_{0} y\left( t \right) e^{-st} dt}{\int^{\infty}_{0} z\left( t \right) e^{-st} dt }$$

Applying the [properties of Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems):

$$ \mathcal{L}\{ \frac{d^2 \, z(t)}{d \, t^2} + 6 \frac{d\, z(t)}{d\, t} + 8 z\left( t
\right) \} = \mathcal{L} \{ \frac{d\, x(t)}{d\, t} + 2x\left( t \right) \} $$
$$ \Rightarrow s^2 \mathcal{L}\{ z\} +6s \mathcal{L}\{ z\} +8 \mathcal{L}\{ z\}
= s\mathcal{L} \{ x\}
+2\mathcal{L} \{ x\}  $$
$$ \Rightarrow H_A(s)= \frac{\mathcal{L} \{ z(t) \}}{\mathcal{L} \{ x(t) \}} =
\frac{s+2}{(s+2)(s+4)}=\frac{1}{s+4} $$
$$ \Rightarrow  h_A=e^{-4t} $$

(in this last line, the original expression was wrong. It was fixed thanks to @KwinvanderVeen) for $s\neq -2$. We also have that:

$$ H_G(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} = \frac{Y(s)}{Z(s)} \frac{Z(s)}{X(s)} = H_B H_A =
\mathcal{L} \{ (h_B*h_A )(t) \} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \mathcal{L}\{ h_G\}=H_G(s)= \mathcal{L}\{ (h_B*h_A)(t) \} $$
$$ \Rightarrow h_G=h_B*h_A = \int_{0}^{t} h_B(\tau ) h_A(t-\tau )d\tau =
e^{-4t}(t e^t-e^t+1) $$

(this last line was also fixed thanks to @KwinvanderVeen). And I think that last line would the the unit impulse response, and the answer to question 1.

Now, I tried to solve question 2 with the suggestions of the same commenter. If the input is periodic, then I think it follows that:

$$ x(t)= e^{1-t} \quad ; \quad 0<t<1 \quad ; \quad T=1 $$ 
$$ x(t)=e^{2-t} \quad ; \quad 1<t<2 \quad ; \quad T=1 $$

And in general, for $n \in \mathbb{N} $:
$$ x(t)=e^{n-t} \quad ; \quad n-1<t<n \quad ; \quad T=1 $$

Then using the formula for the convolution integral:
$$ y(t)= \left( h_G*x \right) (t) =e^{n-t} \int_{n-1}^{n} e^{-3\tau } (\tau e^{\tau} -e^{\tau}
+1 ) d\tau $$

for $n-1<t<n $. Is that the answer? Can i leave the expression like that?

Comment: Your notation is confusing. What is $u(t)$ is it the input to the second system? Hence, I would assume it to be equal to $z(t)$.

Comment: @MachineLearner thank you for the interest. I am sorry I did not specify that, that is the Heaviside step function, also called unit step function. I will edit my post clarifying that.

Comment: You might want to read about convolution integral and Laplace transform.

Comment: @MachineLearner and Obareey, thank you for the comments. Mathematically, I know (the formula) the concepts of [convolution integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) and [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). However, I am still not sure of how to start with this problem. What would a first step be? Or maybe you could offer more hints?

Comment: There are multiple ways of going about this, but I would first work out the transfer function for both systems.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen thanks for your comment. I updated my post.

Comment: @evaristegd but what are the transfer functions, in terms of $s$ explicitly when using what is given about system $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I tried to solve it using your suggestion, and have updated my post. I hope I can receive some feedback.

Comment: Could it be that you made a typo for the impulse response for system A? Namely what you have written down for it is not completely correct, however you total impulse response does seems to be correct.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen , according to the tables, the Laplace transform of $e^{-4t}$ is $\frac{1}{s+4}$. Or is the mistake somewhere else? Please feel free to edit my post if you think it would be too complicated to explain it in the comments.

Comment: Forget my previous comment, I didn't see that you changed $t\,e^{-4\,t}$ to $e^{-4\,t}$.

Comment: you are welcome to submit this question to the [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) if you want to.  it's what it's for.

Comment: @obareey , I have my updated my post, and I would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transfer function and impulse response for system A seem to be correct; good that you also noticed the pole zero cancellation. You could manually calculate the impulse response from the transfer function using the inverse Laplace transform, but in practice it is often easier/quicker to use a Laplace transform table such as [this one](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx). From such a table you should also be able to derive what the (minimal) transfer function should be for system B.

In order to answer question 1 you could indeed do the convolution of the two impulse responses, however I believe that one (me) can easily make mistakes when solving integrals. Instead I would recommend to decompose the total transfer function into a sum of simple terms that appear in a Laplace transform table. For example if the total transfer function is given by

$$
G(s) = \frac{a_2\,s^2 + a_1\,s + a_0}{(s + b_1)^2\,(s + b_2)},
$$

then you would want to solve for $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that

$$
G(s) = \frac{A}{s+b_1} + \frac{B}{(s+b_1)^2} + \frac{C}{s+b_2}.
$$

The total impulse response can then be found by summing the impulse responses of each of the three terms, where impulse response of each term should be able to be found on a a Laplace transform table.

---

Question 2 does not have a completely well defined answer, because no initial conditions are given for system A and B. One way you could interpret this is with all initial conditions set to zero, which can be obtained by evaluating the convolution integral between the input and the impulse response of the total system. Another way is to assume that the output has settled into a period signal as well, which can be obtained by first evaluating the Fourier series of the input

$$
x(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \cos(2\,\pi\,k\,t) + b_k \sin(2\,\pi\,k\,t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \cos(2\,\pi\,k\,t + \phi_k),
$$

the output can then be obtained [using](https://stanford.edu/~boyd/ee102/freq.pdf)

$$
y(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k\,|G(j\,2\,\pi\,k)| \cos(2\,\pi\,k\,t + \phi_k + \angle G(j\,2\,\pi\,k)),
$$

so the total transfer function is evaluated at $s=j\,2\,\pi\,k$, with $j$ the imaginary unit.

This second approach would basically already give the answer to question 3, so I guess the first approach, with the convolution integral, is probably the intended answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! One question, when you say $\angle G(j2\pi k)$, you mean the [arg function for complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) ?

Comment: @evaristegd Yes, I also added a reference to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you again! Regarding your first line, I did get some terms like $-sz(0^{-})-z' (0^{-}) $, but I just assumed they were zero without a specific reason. Why is it that that pole zero cancellation occurs?

Comment: @evaristegd For transfer functions it is indeed assumed that all initial conditions are zero (other wise you can't define a ratio between the Laplace transform of in the input and output).

Comment: Got it. Also, in my post, when I found the expression for $H_A(s)$, and in order to do the cancellation in the fraction, I had to clarify that $s \neq 2$. Is it possible that $s=2$ ? If so, what should I do in that case?

Comment: Also, taking into account your suggestions, I tried to solve Q2, and have updated my post. Any feedback is welcome; your comments so far have been very helpful!

Comment: @evaristegd Note that $x(t)$ is a piecewise function so $y(t)$ will be probably as well. One can find an analytical expression for $y(t)$ when $t$ is an integer and between those times you can evaluate the remaining convolution integral.

Comment: In the last edit to my post (yesterday), indeed, I expressed $y(t) $ as a piecewise function too. Regarding the discontinuities when $t$ is an integer, I thought I could ignore that because the integral would be the same whether we take into account the endpoints or not (in this case, the endpoints would be each integer). Maybe I am missing something? Thank you again for everything!